# reactive Vue component not updating on data change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vuejs3, reactive

I'm new to Vue and trying to display a list of "notes" which update when a button is hit (I've just hardcoded the value to add for now). The trouble is that after I add a new item to the array, this isn't updated in the UI. I'm using Vue3 and The :key I'm using is unique. Other "widgets" I've made have worked as expected but they got data from an api response. Is it related maybe to the async/await aspect of dealing with API responses compared with just appending/pushing to the data array?

```
<template>
 <Widget class="notes" :style="style" @load="showNotes()">
<h3>Notes</h3>
<p v-for="item in data" :key="item.id">{{ item.note }}</p>

<button @click="addNote()">Add</button>
</Widget>
</template>

<script>
import Widget from "./Widget.vue";

export default {
  name: "Notes",
  props: {
    widgetWidth: Number,
  },
  computed: {
    style() {
      return "max-width: " + this.widgetWidth + "px";
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      notes: undefined,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    addNote() {
      var x;
      if (!this.data) {
        this.data = [];
        x = 0;
      } else {
        x = this.data.length;
        console.log(x);
      }
      this.data.push({ id: x, note: "another" });
      console.log(this.data);
    },
    showNotes() {
      this.data = [{ id: 0, note: "init" }];
    },
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.showNotes();
  },
  components: { Widget },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.notes {
  min-width: 100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.notes > * {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's happening because you modify the `data` property and there is no `data` property, it's `notes` property, Also, you don't need the @load event, or beforeMount event to initialize the notes property.

[This working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-field-34xn2p)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is having the same result as I was getting already. The data object is updating and I can see this in the logged console output but still no re-rendering.

Comment: Could you re-produce the issue on any live editor like [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue).

Comment: And make sure that you are using your project Vue version.

Comment: I've just tried doing it in the link you sent. Whenever I share a link from it after editing it reverts back to the template

Comment: make sure after setting your code, to fork the project and click share button and provide me the link inside.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-johnson-zhdd7k

Comment: hopefully this works?

Comment: Also try to save the files by clicking each file `ctrl + S`, before fork and share.

Comment: Sorry, It works, I will check.

Comment: Simply, because you modify `data` and there is no property called `data`, you need to use `notes`.

Comment: Please, check this link. https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-field-34xn2p

Comment: Also, you don't need the `@load` event, or `beforeMount` event to initialize the `notes` property.

Comment: I update the answer, please check.

Comment: Great. Thanks - this has really helped. I just added back the x variable in the id and it's working how I had hoped. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create a computed property called notes that returns the notes property in your data object. In your v-for use item in notes. When you click the button the notes in your data object gets updated. The computed property detects the change and updates the ui

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).